# Installing Rails on Mac os X 10.6.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, installation

I'm new in Ruby on Rails, I'm trying to install rails on mac os x 10.6.8 (i already have `ruby: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin10.0]`), but when I try to see the rails version installed using `$ rails -v`, I get:

```
rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
```

I tried to run:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Of course i tryed to type sudo gem install rails and others options too but no solution, also i tryed to install rvm, this is what i have:

```
$ rvm -v

rvm 1.13.0 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

how can i do to make it work together? or what can i do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem when running OSX 10.7.4. I solved it with the following approach.

Identify the gem manager you're using:

```
$ which gem 
/Users/peter/.rvm/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem
```

Then do a gem update for that specific version:

```
$ gem update --system 1.9.2
```

This took ages to complete, but once finished, `rails -v` returns:

```
Rails 3.2.8
```

Admittedly life shouldn't be this hard. Although I'm used to command line stuff, I'd love to see a graphical tool that allows you to mix, match and confirm what Ruby/Gems are installed on your system.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I am looking at the instructions here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:up_and_running

From your comments you do not have the correct version of ruby installed on your system.

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3@current --create --default
```

The last line creates a gem set called `current`.

Now check to make sure you RubyGems was installed correctly by typing `which gem` in your terminal. Now update your gems.

```
gem update --system 1.8.24
```

Finally install rails.

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.3
```

I hope this works, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: also, don't install rails or any gem via `sudo` if you're using rvm. Rvm installs it into the default ruby. You might need to add the ~/.rvm/gems/<rubyversion>/bin to your path.

Comment: Hi! Im still having this issue, i did a lot of mystakes, for example after type: rvm get head it looked like something installed (what is good, cause untill now i just had a bunch of errors) the thing is that after type that it still showing this:               MacBook-Pro-de-Fernando-Lopez:~ fernando$ rails new_proyect
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
So... i did type again sudo gem install rails (it was before read the new comment). it can be the Xcode?

Comment: @FernandoLöpez first to create a new rails app the command is `rails new myapp` you should double check that rails and ruby are installed correctly by typing `rails -v; ruby -v` in your terminal. Your output should look like this `Rails 3.2.2 \
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]`

Comment: hi! i tryed with rails new myapp and when i type ruby -v i get this: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin10.0]
and rails -v: Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.
i tryed everything and i cant found the solution,

Comment: i even installed windows on mac to use "irails" everything "works fine" untill i wanna do a scaffold named "product" (for example) then i get this error: Routing Error
No route matches "/products" with {:method=>:get} .it is something with the databases? or what is going on?

Comment: @FernandoLöpez I have updated my answer to summarize the install instructions.

Comment: thanks a lot for that! im gonna try right now! thanks again for your concern!

Comment: 2 things 1)THANK YOU VERY MUCH @trev9065 the solution you gave me was very very helpfull (it was the way i installed everything now) 2) i updated to xcode4 (this was seems to be the principal problem). Again thank you very much for the help, i hope i can help too like you do somethime

Comment: thanks! works for me, don't need to upgrade XCode as the log indicates

Answer (score 0):

I've had great luck using the [Rails Ready](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) script on OSX. Can't say about Lion from personal experience but its always worked great on Snow Leopard.